# How do I do a Simple PHP Loop repetition

Tags: php

Please follow alone, I will explain a simple loop issue.

```
for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
    $test= $k;
    echo $test; /// 123456789
}

echo $test; //// 9
```

as you can see, when I echo $test outside the loop, the results is 9. HOw can one echo $test outside the loop with all $k's values..

example.

```
for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
    $test= $k;
}

echo $test; //// 123456789
```

Comment: what you are seeing in the first example is not 1 echo but 9 seperate echo's without a newline between them, meaning that $test does never contain "123456789" it contains one at the time and prints then in sequence. You wanna concat the result inorder to have it in $test after the loop.

Comment: Amazing how everyone has posted the exact same answer

Comment: @someshMukherjee: And even more amazing how they have neglected to tell him what he's doing wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone, you all have been sweet. I am new to SOF and i have never been to a site that has such talented members and so enthusiasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update like this

```
$test[] = $k;
```

then use a foreach to retrieve the values.

```
Foreach($test as $value){

echo $value;

}
```

Comment: Yours is very interesting, thanks for the different perspective.

Comment: so basically you run through all the elemnts and store them in an array. Then run through all the elements in that array again to retrieve them?

Comment: In this particular case, the two iteration may seem unnecessary but what if later he wants to retrieve a particular number or a set of numbers which aren't consecutive? Instead of putting conditionals, retrieving them will be much easier as it provides more flexibility. On that case this one will come handy.

Comment: how is this different from what he did in his first example? and you do is add extra mem usage.

Answer (score 3):

try using [.=](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) string operator

```
$test = "";

for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
    $test .= $k;
}
```

Comment: $test has to be declared outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to string them together.

```
$test = "";

for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
    $test .= $k;
}

echo $test; //// 123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

Period (`.`) is use for concatenation in PHP.

```
for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
    $test .= $k;
}

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be

```
$test = "";
for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
    $test.=$k;
}

echo $test; //// 123456789
```

That is, make test into a string and add the number at the end for every iteration. When the loop is done, print the string.

Answer (score 0):

YOu cannot access $test outside the loop. The scope is local besides, the value of $test changes with every loop

What you want to do is: Store it in an string declared outside the loop to concat every time

```
$test="";
for($k=1;$k <10; $k++){
$test= $test.$k;

}
```

echo $test; //// 1235567890

Having said that, I dun think you should be doing this. If you post what exactly you are trying to do, we could help you

Comment: *... cannot access $test outside the loop. The scope is local besides, ...* - there is no block-scope in php.